# How to install Darwin Ports or Mac Ports on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macports

### Update:

Don't waste your time with MacPorts. I would recommend using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) instead. It's easy to use and doesn't clutter up your system with a bunch of junk directories.

---

**Update: Don't install Darwin Ports.** Darwin Ports is a fake. Also, I did not have a great experience using MacPorts, so I don't recommend using it.

---

### Original Question:

So I decided to download and install [Darwin Ports](http://darwinports.com/) to make my life a little easier. I ran the installer and it seemed to install just fine. But when I run `sudo port -d selfupdate` like the documentation says to do, I get some sort of message:

```
 dlopen(/opt/local/share/macports/Tcl/pextlib1.0/Pextlib.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find: /opt/local/share/macports/Tcl/pextlib1.0/Pextlib.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper while executing "load /opt/local/share/macports/Tcl/pextlib1.0/Pextlib.dylib" ("package ifneeded Pextlib 1.0" script) invoked from within "package require Pextlib 1.0" (file "/opt/local/bin/port" line 40)
```

I don't know what that means or what I should do. Any suggestions? I also don't know the difference between Darwin Ports and MacPorts. Maybe I am trying to install the wrong thing?

**Update:** I decided to install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) to see what would happen. I was able to download the version of the [MacPorts package installer for Snow Leopard](https://www.macports.org/install.php), install MacPorts and run `sudo port -v selfupdate` (note the -v difference) and get it to update correctly. Now I am trying to install phpMyAdmin by doing `sudo port install phpmyadmin` but I get this error message:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for phpmyadmin
Error: Unable to execute port: can't read "build.cmd": Failed to locate 'make' in path: '/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin' or at its MacPorts configuration time location, did you move it?
```

Did I miss a step in installing MacPorts?

**Update:** Turns out I needed to re-install the newest version of Xcode.

Comment: Please note that **darwinports.com is bogus**. See the [DarwinPorts History](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/DarwinPorts) page at MacPorts.

Comment: A suggestion from my experience: be careful with MacPorts.  I don't know what specifically you're going to use it for and what I actually did to cause this, but using MacPorts managed to hose my python installation.  I had something like 3 interpreters in various locations all at different versions and all only having some of my libraries installed.  It was a mess, and that's why I try to stay away when possible.  ./configure && make && sudo make install isn't particularly difficult most of the time.

Comment: Try fink. I've had much better luck with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you installed XCode before? My `make` is in `/usr/bin` so I think it’s got nothing to do with Macports itself but must be supplied by other means.

**Update**:

According to [this macports ticket](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/21224) you might have two options. First you could check, whether make is in `/Developer/usr/bin`. If so, you could enable the `binpath` in `/opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf` and add this path to it. (Though using the binpath explicitly is flagged as *advanced* in the file.

The other option is, of course, reinstalling XCode. And this time be careful to select ‘Unix Development Support’ while you’re at it. There’s a chance that you’ve missed this when installing it the last time.

If make has gone missing for some other reason, there *might* be something pretty wrong with your system, so it’s better to assume that it’s never been installed before…

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have XCode installed and running correctly.

Comment: "Pretty sure" or absolute sure? You have to have XCode installed for MacPorts to work (it uses some components installed with XCode).

Comment: ok...Absolutely Sure. I have already installed Xcode and have used it before. I have even opened it after upgrading to Snow Leopard to make sure it still worked. Though, there's nothing in /usr/bin called make

Comment: @misbehavens I am pretty sure that you need Xcode 3.2 with Snow Leopard (install it from your Snow Leopard DVD, or download it from Apple via a free ADC account). Any older versions will probably break in one way or another.

Comment: Okay...just installed Xcode 3.2 and now make shows up in /usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing [MacPort](http://www.macports.org/) (1.8.2) using source code. Not sure how it works though.

> The MacPorts Project is an open-source community initiative to design
>   an easy-to-use system for compiling, installing, and upgrading either
>   command-line, X11 or Aqua based open-source software on the Mac OS X
>   operating system. To that end we provide the command-line driven
>   MacPorts software package under a BSD License, and through it easy
>   access to thousands of ports that greatly simplify the task of
>   compiling and installing open-source software on your Mac.
>
> We provide a single software tree that attempts to track the latest
>   release of every software title (port) we distribute, without
>   splitting them into “stable” Vs. “unstable” branches, targeting mainly
>   the current Mac OS X release (10.7, A.K.A Lion) and the immediately
>   previous one (10.6, A.K.A. Snow Leopard). There are currently 15361
>   ports in our tree, distributed among 98 different categories, and more
>   are being added on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine working after following this site - https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/wiki/MacPorts